# GWT HTMLPanel Height Issue

Tags: css, gwt

I am using GWT HtmlPanel to group the widgets. I want to set the height for the HtmlPanel as 100% using CSS. and set the background-color to it.

**Here it is my code:**

**CSS:**
.loginhtmlpan {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #424242;
}

please help me in this context.

Comment: You can try to set the height and width with your java code. use `setHeight` or `setWidth`. Also add the tag css to your question. It isn't really a gwt issue but more a css issue. When you do this you will get better input.

Answer (score 1):

Try using constraint-based CSS positioning rather than specifying specific heights and widths programmatically. This is becoming common practice for standard GWT-widgets. A style like:

.myCssStyle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

You can then add this style to your HTMLPanel using the addStyleName("myCssStyle") - the nice thing about this is that proper resizing of your HTMLPanel will occur for free when browser resize events occur. As a side note, most GWT "Layout" containers use constraint-based positioning (DockLayoutPanel, LayoutPanel, SplitLayoutPanel, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to apply a css style to a gwt widget:

1. Link the stylesheet in your host.html file.
2. call `myHtmlPanel.addStyleName("loginhtmlplan")` when you create the html panel

See http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html for more details